# Porque mi procedimiento almacenado no regresa valores a mi php

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedure

tengo un pequeño problema, 
La ejecución de mi procedimiento almacenado desde mi `php` no regresa valores:
`$op=1;` la variable `$op` contiene el numero de mi procedimiento 
la variable `$cadena` contiene  la busqueda para el where

```
$SP="[ele].[Buscar_clientes]".$op.",".$cadena."'";
$recordSet=$fn->SP_BD($SP); 
comppruebo si hay datos
if(!$recordSet->EOF){
 while{....}
}else{
echo "error";
}
```

Imprimo mi variable `$SP` para comprobar que ejecuta

```
[ele].[Buscar_clientes]1,'Mario|Juan'
```

y lo ejecuto en mi sql y trae los datos que busco pero en mi php cae en el error

Ya he usado otros procedimientos para insertar  y actualizar pero el problema solo es cuando tengo un procedimiento que trae datos.

Comment: que motor de BD estás usando? el código que pusiste es seudocodigo, no? que driver de PHP estás usando?

Comment: Hola... estoy usando sql server 2008 y si es sintaxis de php , ademas usando "odbc_mssql",
Ese procedimiento lo ejecuto como cualquier otro query, y no se si estoy mal pero deberia devolver algo, lo he probado en base y esta perfecto ya que ahi si regresa datos ... perdón por no contestar.